# Why does git clone prompt for 'passphrase for key' when I SSH to my machine as my user?

Tags: ssh, git

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. When I am logged in normally and I run a git clone it works without issues -

```
wesley@localhost:~/Temp$ git clone ssh://git@xyz.pqr.com:5678/abc/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: ...
...
...
```

This works without me needing to enter any username or password or passphrase. My ssh config looks as follows -

```
wesley@localhost:~/.ssh$ ls -alt
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 97 wesley wesley  4096 Jun 26 10:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wesley wesley 32718 Jun 25 11:44 known_hosts
drwx------  2 wesley wesley  4096 Mar 28 11:09 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 wesley wesley   963 Feb  9  2018 config
-rw-------  1 wesley wesley  3326 May 26  2017 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 wesley wesley   750 May 26  2017 id_rsa.pub
```

However, let's say I SSH to my own machine with my own user. Then the 'git clone' asks me to "Enter passphrase for key '/home/wesley/.ssh/id_rsa'"

```
wesley@localhost:~/Temp$ ssh wesley@localhost
wesley@localhost's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64)
...
...
wesley@localhost:~$ cd Temp/
wesley@localhost:~/Temp$
wesley@localhost:~/Dump$ git clone ssh://git@xyz.pqr.com:5678/abc/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/wesley/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Why is the behavior different when I SSH?

Comment: You probably have an SSH Agent running when logged in via the GUI. Probably Seahorse if on GNOME.

Comment: can you check, if this happens when you enable agent forwarding (`ssh -A wesley@localhost`)?

Comment: @blissini, thanks! When I use the -A option the git clone works like before.